# Size information when overloading C++ new operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator

The C++ memory allocation operator has the form of `operator new (size_t s)`. When I overload the `new` operator for a class object of type `T`, does it guarantee the input argument (i.e., `size_t s`) of the operator `new` is exactly `sizeof(T)`? If yes, why does this function still need the size as input argument?

Comment: This isn't my field, but [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) could be helpful.

Answer (score 14):

It is possible to override operator new in a base class and use it to allocate objects of derived class type.

```
struct Base
{
    void* operator new (size_t s) { ... }
    int a;
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
   int b;
};

Derived* d = new Derived;
```

When allocating memory for `Derived`, `Base::operator new(size_t)` will be used. The value of the argument will be `sizeof(Derived)`. Without that argument, the compiler cannot allocate the right amount of memory for an object of type `Derived`.